Embedding of a nilpotent algebraic group in upper triangular matrices
Suppose we have a polynomial group law on $G=\mathbb{R}^n$ which gives it a structure of a nilpotent algebraic group.

Is it true that there exists an embedding of $G$ into the group of upper-triangular matrices with $1$-s on the diagonal?

If the answer to the previous question is "yes",  is there an algorithm of finding such an embedding explicitly ( having a group law on $G$)?




yes, the law being polynomial on an affine space forces $G$ to be unipotent. 2) this basically contains Ado's theorem (for nilpotent Lie algebras) which is quite hard (but this might be "algorithmic" at least in principle, I'm not sure)


@YCor, will the embedding itself also be polynomial?

Yes: every continuous group homomorphism between two groups of this form ($\mathbf{R}^n$, nilpotent polynomial group law) is polynomial.

Thanks @YCor. Could you provide a reference please?
